# Android: strange thing about loading contact info

Tags: android, contacts

I created an app. It is working on htc desire hd, but when i tested it on ZTE Blade, a strange problem appeared. In my app when user selects a contact name from a spinner a menu appears. In the menu the user can send sms to the user, call him/her or just look at his/her contact info. On HTC Desire HD, everything is working fine. On ZTE there seems to be an exasperating problem with the contact info button: In certain cases when user selects a contact and wants to see his contact info, some other contact's info is shown. So I select Pete from my spinner but I get Dave's contact info. In other cases I select Tom from the spinner and I get Tom's contact info. The problem is not existing on my HTC. I couldn't figure out what causes the problem. By the way, my contact list on HTC is populated also from gmail and facebook and the app still working fine, while the contact list of the ZTE has never seen any gmail or facebook accounts (i am not entirely sure about this).

This is the code i am using to get to the contact info:

```
         infobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
                {

                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    id_contact = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name_contact = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        if (name_contact.equals(name1))
                        {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id_contact}, null);
                           id_contact2 = id_contact;

                            while (pCur.moveToNext()){
                            } 
                        pCur.close();
                        }
                    }
                    Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/" + id_contact2));
                    startActivity(intent_contacts);
                }

            }
         });
```

Comment: No one? I experienced this on Xperia 10 as well.

Comment: I was thinking...what if this is caused by imported contacts? There are no imported contacts on my phone. That is why I do not encounter any problems, but on all the other phones, the contacts were imported from Symbian. Maybe this messes up the contact id-s. E.g. my colleague cannot separate the imported contact: Charles Dickens on his phone, it is just Charles Dickens. No first name, no surname, just simply a name. What do you think?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems in my application. The app is a widget that give possibility to use favorites contacts in fast way. User creates new widget and assigns contact to it. When he clicks on widget he is able to make common contact actions - call, sms, edit, etc.

Some users send report like this one: 
"I select about 4 contacts and the app shows 4 but only one of them right 3 others is same contact which I didnt even picked".
"Why does the wrong contact show when picked? On my droid incredible"

I can't reproduce the problem on my side. I have tried several different devices, tried to make import/export contacts - no results.

Anyway, i have some ideas about source of the problem.

My application uses lookup keys to store contacts, [according to sdk](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html). So, when user picks up a contact, application stores contact lookup key. Then it uses this lookup key to get Contact ID for this contact. After that, it uses ONLY received Contact ID in all other functions. So does your function - it uses only Contact ID in sub-query.

The question is: is it possible that different contacts (with different lookup keys) have same Contact ID?  It looks like it's possible on some devices in rare cases... <strike>If so, we need to use Contact ID + lookup key always together to identify contact.</strike> (**update: the suggestion was incorrect. Lookup key can be changed after contact info modification, you won't find contact**).

As I understand, you are able to reproduce the problem on your side. I would suggest to change your code in such way:

```
     infobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { 
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
            {

                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                id_contact = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name_contact = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String lookup_key = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    if (name_contact.equals(name1))
                    {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?", new String[]{id_contact, lookup_key}, null);
                       id_contact2 = id_contact;

                        while (pCur.moveToNext()){
                        } 
                    pCur.close();
                    }
                }
                Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/" + id_contact2));
                startActivity(intent_contacts);
            }

        }
     });
```

and try to reproduce the problem again.

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion was wrong. It's incorrect to search contact by lookup_key in this way because lookup key can be changed after contact info modification.

Comment: I have found the reason of the problem. In rare cases, on some devices lookup keys are not unique. Take a look on the part of log file that i have got from one of my app users:                
k=1957i5 c=153; k=1957i46d39cd0743de699 c=154; k=1957i327657105acc3975 c=155; k=1957i5 c=394; k=1957i300808f8df4189b1 c=156; k=1957i5 c=158;                  k=1957i660d8a742c21a4a6 c=411; Here: "k" is lookup key value, "c" is contactId. So, it's not enough to use lookup id as reference on contact. It's necessary to store pair "contactId - lookupKey".

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link, It's very good: http://www.vtutorials.info/2014/08/working-with-android-contacts-how-to.html

```
private Map<Long, ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>> queryAllPhones(ContentResolver contentresolver)  
   {  
     HashMap<Long, ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>> hashmap = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>>();  
     Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;  
           String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;  
           String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;  
     Cursor cursor = contentresolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);  
     do  
     {  
       if (!cursor.moveToNext())  
       {  
         cursor.close();  
         return hashmap;  
       }  
       long l = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone_CONTACT_ID));  
       String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));  
       LocalContactInfo temp = new LocalContactInfo(String.valueOf(l), "", s, "", 1);  
       if (hashmap.containsKey(Long.valueOf(l))){  
         ((List<LocalContactInfo>)hashmap.get(Long.valueOf(l))).add(temp);  
       } else{  
         ArrayList<LocalContactInfo> arraylist = new ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>();  
         arraylist.add(temp);  
         hashmap.put(Long.valueOf(l), arraylist);  
       }  
     } while (true);  
   }
```

And:

```
 public List<LocalContactInfo> doloadContacts() {  
           List<LocalContactInfo> _return = new ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>();  
           Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;  
           String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;  
           String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;  
           String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;  
           ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();  
           Map<Long, ArrayList<LocalContactInfo>> map = queryAllPhones(contentResolver);  
           Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  
           if(cursor == null || cursor.getCount()==0){  
             return _return;  
        }  
           if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {  
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {  
                     Long contact_id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));  
                     String fullname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME )).trim();  
                     int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));  
                     if (hasPhoneNumber > 0 && map.get(contact_id) != null){  
                               Object obj = ((List<LocalContactInfo>)map.get(contact_id)).get(0);  
                               if(obj instanceof LocalContactInfo){  
                                    LocalContactInfo _temp = (LocalContactInfo)obj;  
                                    _return.add(new LocalContactInfo(String.valueOf(contact_id), fullname, _temp.getNumberPhone(), "",hasPhoneNumber));  
                               }  
                     }  
             }  
           }  
     return _return;  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "contacts/people/xxx", try using contactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

basically, you want to replace.

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/" + id_contact2));
```

with

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
    id_contact2);
```

Another thing to note is that "id_contact2" may be changed if a sync occurs before you use it (like when google sync merges a contact). To prevent this, it might be better to use a LookupKey instead.

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
```

and retrieve using

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, 
    yourContactLookupKey);
```